# use .htaccess only for visitors on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am protecting a specific folder via 404 redirect, using .htaccess. I don't want visitors who call the folder directly in the browser to even know it exists (thus 404).

However when I log into the admin panel as admin, my plugin does need to access that folder.

Is there a way I can use .htaccess only for visitors?

I did come across this https://www.willmaster.com/blog/contentprotection/htaccess-cookie.php which explains on how .htaccess can check for specific cookies, but from what I understnd, WordPress sets cookies with hashes in the cookie name like `wordpress_logged_in_d60620f61b153d46087aadf37d936a00`, therefore I can't check for the cookie name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond uses regular expressions, so you can match for part of the string, e.g. just check for `wordpress_logged_in_` in the Cookie.

However, this can easily be spoofed, the client can send cookies as it pleases. When I'm working on WP sites, I generally always add a cookie with `wordpress_logged_in_something` to my requests to make sure I bypass caches. That would only block people who don't try that.
Also, it wouldn't check whether that cookie is still a valid session.

In general, you can't do that with mod_rewrite. Use HTTP Authentication or run it through a PHP script.

What's inside that folder that you want to protect? A simple PHP script that reads the cookies, checks that they are valid WP cookies from an admin user, and then returns the content of the file you're looking for might be all you need.